# Python's multiprocessing: speed up a for-loop for several sets of parameters, "apply" vs. "apply_async"

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing, odeint

I would like to integrate a system of differential equations using a lot of different parameter combinations and store the variables’ final values that belong to a certain set of parameters. Therefore, I implemented a simple for-loop in which random initial conditions and parameter combinations are created, the system is integrated and the values of interest are stored in the respective arrays.
Since I intend to do this for many parameter combinations for a rather complex system (here I only use a toy system for illustration), which can also become stiff, I would like to parallelize the simulations to speed up the process using Python’s “multiprocessing” module.

However, when I run the simulations, the for-loop is always faster than its parallelized version. The only way to be faster than the for-loop I’ve found so far, is to use “apply_async” instead of “apply”. For 10 different parameter combinations, I get for example the following output (using the code from below):

```
The for loop took  0.11986207962 seconds!
[ 41.75971761  48.06034375  38.74134139  25.6022232   46.48436046
  46.34952734  50.9073202   48.26035086  50.05026187  41.79483135]
Using apply took  0.180637836456 seconds!
41.7597176061
48.0603437545
38.7413413879
25.6022231983
46.4843604574
46.3495273394
50.9073202011
48.2603508573
50.0502618731
41.7948313502
Using apply_async took  0.000414133071899 seconds!
41.7597176061
48.0603437545
38.7413413879
25.6022231983
46.4843604574
46.3495273394
50.9073202011
48.2603508573
50.0502618731
41.7948313502
```

Although in this example the order of the results are identical for “apply” and “apply_async”, this seems not to be true in general. So, I would like to use “apply_async” since it is much faster but in this case I don’t know how I can match the outcome of the simulations to the parameters/initial conditions I used for the respective simulation.

My questions are therefore:

1) Why is “apply” much slowlier than the simple for-loop in this case?

2) When I use “apply_async” instead of “apply“, the parallelized version becomes very much faster than the for-loop but how can I then match the outcome of the simulations to the parameters I used in the respective simulation?

3) In this case, the results of “apply” and “apply_async” have the same order. Why is that? Coincidence?

My code can be found below:

```
from pylab import *
import multiprocessing as mp
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import time

#my system of differential equations
def myODE (yn,tvec,allpara):

    (x, y, z) = yn

    a, b = allpara['para']

    dx  = -x + a*y + x*x*y
    dy = b - a*y - x*x*y
    dz = x*y

    return (dx, dy, dz) 

#for reproducibility    
seed(0) 

#time settings for integration
dt = 0.01
tmax = 50
tval = arange(0,tmax,dt)

numVar = 3 #number of variables (x, y, z)
numPar = 2 #number of parameters (a, b)
numComb = 10 #number of parameter combinations

INIT = zeros((numComb,numVar)) #initial conditions will be stored here
PARA = zeros((numComb,numPar)) #parameter combinations for a and b will be stored here
RES = zeros(numComb) #z(tmax) will be stored here

tic = time.time()

for combi in range(numComb):

    INIT[combi,:] = append(10*rand(2),0) #initial conditions for x and y are randomly chosen, z is 0

    PARA[combi,:] = 10*rand(2) #parameter a and b are chosen randomly

    allpara = {'para': PARA[combi,:]}

    results = transpose(odeint(myODE, INIT[combi,:], tval, args=(allpara,))) #integrate system

    RES[combi] = results[numVar - 1][-1] #store z

    #INIT[combi,:] = results[:,-1] #update initial conditions
    #INIT[combi,-1] = 0 #set z to 0

toc = time.time()

print 'The for loop took ', toc-tic, 'seconds!'

print RES

#function for the multi-processing part
def runMyODE(yn,tvec,allpara):

    return transpose(odeint(myODE, yn, tvec, args=(allpara,)))

tic = time.time()

pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
results = [pool.apply(runMyODE, args=(INIT[combi,:],tval,{'para': PARA[combi,:]})) for combi in range(numComb)]

toc = time.time()

print 'Using apply took ', toc-tic, 'seconds!'

for sol in range(numComb):
    print results[sol][2,-1] #print final value of z

tic = time.time()    
resultsAsync = [pool.apply_async(runMyODE, args=(INIT[combi,:],tval,{'para': PARA[combi,:]})) for combi in range(numComb)]    
toc = time.time()
print 'Using apply_async took ', toc-tic, 'seconds!'

for sol in range(numComb):
    print resultsAsync[sol].get()[2,-1] #print final value of z
```

Comment: As pointed out in the current answer, your asynchronous apply is bogus since you're not letting the work finish before you print out a time. The whole point of asynchronicity is to avoid blocking the calling thread while the work is being done. That said, the first rule of getting real performance gains out of parallel loop processing is to ensure that each thread/task has a sufficient amount of work to do. There's a greater overhead scheduling threads to do these tasks than a single-threaded for loop, so you have to make up for that overhead by doing significantly more in each iteration.

Comment: For example, if you want to parallelize something like calculating vertex normals, you'll harm performance if each iteration of the loop just calculates one vertex's normal. You want each iteration to calculate thousands of normals to make up for that thread scheduling overhead. Write the code that way so that each thread has very meaty work to do, and you'll start to see speed ups that start to become increasingly proportional to your hardware capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Ike! My - apparently - naive idea was that if I have a certain amount of parameter combinations and in a for-loop it takes me an amount T to integrate them, I would end up with a time ~T/4 if I use a parallel approach with 4 cores. You are right that in this particular example the computational tasks are not that "meaty". However, there are systems for which the random parameters lead to a stiff system which results in long integration times. While waiting for such a stiff system to be integrated, I wanted to integrate several non-stiff systems at the same time.

Comment: You can always make any loopy logic meatier by processing sub-ranges inside the loop and get something approaching those kinds of speed boosts. For example, if you are processing a range of 2000 elements and each iteration is not meaty enough, you can always turn that into a case like where the outer loop processes a range `i=0,19`, and each nested loop is processing `j=i*100,(i+1)*100`. You can also write like a wrapper which does this for you -- one of the reasons these libs usually don't do that is probably because they want to leave it up to you to decide how to make things meaty enough.

Comment: But I got bitten in much the same way when I first started using Intel's Thread Building Blocks. I tried simply doing a one-to-one translation of some of my previous, most performance-critical loops into parallel fors only for the entire application to slow down (making it worse than the single-threaded solutions before). I was really disappointed until I realized that I needed to make each parallel for loop iteration much, much meatier, and then I started seeing the exciting performance gains I was hoping for.

Comment: The next question you might have might be how meaty each thread iteration should be. I'd say just time it as you are doing now with different sub-ranges and you'll start getting a sense of it. In my case, if I use calculating the normals of triangles as a comparison, each normal calculation involves quite a hefty amount of arithmetic as well as mem accesses (though likely to be cached). We found that we had to calculate ~4096 triangle normals per thread iteration before we started approaching the theoretical peak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the fact that your apply_async is 289 times faster then the for loop is a little suspicious!  And right now, you're guaranteed to get the results in the order they're submitted, even if that isn't what you want for maximum parallelism.

apply_async starts a task, it doesn't wait until it's completed; .get() does that.  So this:

```
tic = time.time()    
resultsAsync = [pool.apply_async(runMyODE, args=(INIT[combi,:],tval,{'para': PARA[combi,:]})) for combi in range(numComb)]    
toc = time.time()
```

Isn't really a very fair measurement; you've started all the tasks, but they're not necessarily completed yet.

On the other hand, once you .get() the results, you know that the task has completed and that you have the answer; so doing this

```
for sol in range(numComb):
    print resultsAsync[sol].get()[2,-1] #print final value of z
```

Means that for sure you have the results in order (because you're going through the ApplyResult objects in order and .get()ing them); but you might want to have the results as soon as they're ready rather than doing a blocking wait on the steps one at a time. But that means you'd need to label the results with their parameters one way or another.

You can use callbacks to save the results once the tasks are done, and return the parameters along with the results, to allow completely asynchronous returns:

```
def runMyODE(yn,tvec,allpara):
    return allpara['para'],transpose(odeint(myODE, yn, tvec, args=(allpara,)))

asyncResults = []

def saveResult(result):
    asyncResults.append((result[0], result[1][2,-1]))

tic = time.time()
for combi in range(numComb):
    pool.apply_async(runMyODE, args=(INIT[combi,:],tval,{'para': PARA[combi,:]}), callback=saveResult)
pool.close()
pool.join()
toc = time.time()

print 'Using apply_async took ', toc-tic, 'seconds!'

for res in asyncResults:
    print res[0], res[1]
```

Gives you a more reasonable time; the results are still almost always in order because the tasks take very similar amounts of time:

```
Using apply took  0.0847041606903 seconds!
[ 6.02763376  5.44883183] 41.7597176061
[ 4.37587211  8.91773001] 48.0603437545
[ 7.91725038  5.2889492 ] 38.7413413879
[ 0.71036058  0.871293  ] 25.6022231983
[ 7.78156751  8.70012148] 46.4843604574
[ 4.61479362  7.80529176] 46.3495273394
[ 1.43353287  9.44668917] 50.9073202011
[ 2.64555612  7.74233689] 48.2603508573
[ 0.187898    6.17635497] 50.0502618731
[ 9.43748079  6.81820299] 41.7948313502
Using apply_async took  0.0259671211243 seconds!
[ 4.37587211  8.91773001] 48.0603437545
[ 0.71036058  0.871293  ] 25.6022231983
[ 6.02763376  5.44883183] 41.7597176061
[ 7.91725038  5.2889492 ] 38.7413413879
[ 7.78156751  8.70012148] 46.4843604574
[ 4.61479362  7.80529176] 46.3495273394
[ 1.43353287  9.44668917] 50.9073202011
[ 2.64555612  7.74233689] 48.2603508573
[ 0.187898    6.17635497] 50.0502618731
[ 9.43748079  6.81820299] 41.7948313502
```

Note that rather than looping over apply, you could also use map:

```
pool.map_async(lambda combi: runMyODE(INIT[combi,:], tval, para=PARA[combi,:]), range(numComb), callback=saveResult)
```

Comment: I do not get this "map_async" line to run. All I do is to replace the lines "for combi in range(numComb):
    pool.apply_async(runMyODE, args=(INIT[combi,:],tval,{'para': PARA[combi,:]}), callback=saveResult)" by the line with the "pool.map_async" but then nothing is printed. Any suggestions? Could you maybe edit your code for this example?! Thanks! Furthermore, are pool.close() and pool.join() required or "only" good style?

Comment: @Cleb: It looks like there is a bug in map_async() in some quite recent versions of Python where the callback parameter is ignored (this would result in the results list being empty, which is what you're seeing).  Newest (or old enough!) versions should work. As for close() and join(), that's what you'd want to do to tidy up, and it means that the map will be finished as well, but you could just as easily call wait() on all the results, or (if map_async works) get a single return value from map_async and return. It'd also be worth trying just map().

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have been more precise. By saying "nothing is printed" I also included the function "RunMyODE" and "myODE" which are not called using map_async. But the apply_async works fine and it is faster than the simple for-loop which answered my original question (therefore I accepted your answer). In case you would like to get a second accepted answer, you could comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30289153/multiprocessing-in-python-how-to-implement-a-loop-over-apply-async-as-map-as) where I specifically ask about using map_async for this example.

Comment: One can make a very dirty workaround by adding another function and then avoid the "lamda" call: "def runode(combi):
   allpara = {'para': PARA[combi,:]}
   return runMyODE(INIT[combi,:], tval, {'para': PARA[combi,:], 'index': combi})" then one can simple call "pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
result = pool.map_async(runode, range(numComb))
print result.get()"
but this is not faster than the apply and feels wrong.